# How to show a given algebra is not generated by one element

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose I have a $k$-algebra $k[x,y]/\langle f\rangle$, where $f$ is a (given, fixed) irreducible polynomial. What are the strategies for showing that this isn't generated by one element as a $k$-algebra?

Comment: It would be useful if you explained what sort of example youhave in mind. It is very hard to write an answer that is useful to *you* if we don't know what *you* want (and know) You asked for "the startegies", and at that level of generality there is a lot of things that are not going to be useful for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your algebra $A=k[X,Y]/(f)$ is monogenic, i.e. generated by a single element, the class of a  polynomial  $P(X,Y)$, then $A$  is  of the form $A=k[P(x,y)]$ and since $P(x,y)$ is transcendental over $k$ this means that $A$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring: $A\simeq k[T]$.

This implies that the curve $C=V(f)\subset \mathbb A^2(k)$ or its projective closure $\bar C=V(f_{hom})\subset \mathbb P^2(k)$ is rational ( $ f_h(X,Y,Z$ being the homogeneization of $f(X,Y)$), which is relatively easy to check.

For example, if $char(k)=0$ and $f(X,Y)=X^n+Y^n-1=0$, the algebra $A$ is generated by one element if and only if $n=1$  .
Indeed the curve $\bar C$ given by $X^n+Y^n-Z^n=0$ is smooth of genus $g=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ and is thus not rational for $n\geq 3$ since  then  $g\geqq 1$ .
For  $n=2$ we can reduce to the rational curve $X'Y'-1=0$ by an obvious  change of  variables, but:

**Warning**
 Even if $C$ is rational, the algebra $A$ need  not be monogenic: think of $f=XY-1$  for which  $A=k[X,X^{-1}]$ is *not* monogenic.
Indeed if it were, it would be generated by a transcendental element $T$ (as mentioned above) and would thus be isomorphic to $k[T]$.
 But the algebras  $k[T]$ and $A=k[X,X^{-1}]$    are not isomorphic: the only invertible elements of $k[T]$ are the  non-zero constants, $(k[T])^*=k^*$, whereas $(k[X,X^{-1}])^*=\bigcup _{m\in \mathbb Z}k^*X^m$, a much bigger group.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but my question is motivated by a homework question which does not assume the knowledge required to understand your answer (i.e. I don't know what you're talking about yet). I was hoping for a more algebraic answer, but perhaps there isn't one; maybe it's too case-specific.

Comment: @Matt: in that case, you should probably specify $f$.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry to hear that, @Matt. I hope this answer may be of use to you in the future or to some users now. I would guess that there are not many examples of monogenic algebras besides those corresponding to $f=Y-\phi(X)$ or $f=X-\psi (Y)$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Re: Your "warning", why not?

Comment: @Matt: I have added an explanation for the non-isomorphism of the algebras  $k[T]$ and $k[X,X^{-1}]$ at the end of my answer.